# compatibility TFS Update 1 backups on TFS Update 2 backups?

Tags: tfs, backup

We just learned this morning that in TFS 2012 Update 2 they integrated backups in TFS rather than you having to install the power tools to get backup functionality. Is there any compatibility picture between the backups created with update 1 & the power tools with the scheduled backup feature in TFS 2012 Update 2? Our production server is running 2012 update 1 and the other machine we are trying to restore is running 2012 Update 2.

We are trying to restore a backup of prod to this other server but when we choose "List Backups" in the Restore Database functionality of the Scheduled Backup tool it doesn't list anything when we point it to our production backup folder.

Comment: Does the folder contain `BackupSets.xml`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rules are rather simple:

- When restoring a non-detached collection backup, you *must* restore to the same version. TFS will balk if they're not at the same level. An upgrade will change data structures and stored procedures.
- When restoring a collection that has been detached you can restore and attach it to the same version or (most) newer versions (there are limitations, for example: 2012 rtm and 2012u4 can be attached to 2013, but TFS 2012u1, 2 and 3 cannot)
- You cannot restore a backup from a higher version on an older version of TFS. You must first upgrade the target server.